# FileZilla View / Edit Keyboard Shortcut (or hotkey) to open file in System Editor

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, filezilla

Right now, I just want to open file from server in system default editor.

I can right-click and *View/Edit* Context Menu and it works.

[image: how do i create hotkey shortcut to view/edit file in local editor?]

That is just to truckin' slow because [I'm a power level 9000 user](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik)!. I hunted down the [wiki keyboard shortcut page](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Keyboard_shortcuts) but I was thinking, "maybe someone forgot to update this page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Select the file, then

1. Click the <kbd>context menu</kbd> key,
2. followed by the <kbd>V</kbd> key.

[image]

The <kbd>context menu</kbd> key is this one:

[image]

<sub>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key</sub>

#### Solution 2 with AutoHotkey

If installing [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com) is an option, here is another way.

Use this script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class wxWindowNR   ; Only run when FileZilla has focus
v::                                 ; Set "v" for "view" as the keyboard shortcut 
Send {AppsKey}                      ; Press the "context menu" key
Sleep 100                           ; Give the context menu time to appear
Send v                              ; Press v for "View/Edit"
return
```

Afterwards, select a file, then

1. click <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: thanks buddy for the idea! that's a good way to speed things, but just not efficient enough to remember. still faster to manually click 3 extra times imho.

Comment: @MaggewDotCom I've added another solution.